# MapPoint Web Service Zoom Level

Tags: mappoint

I am modifying an application that someone else wrote for MapPoint Web Service. Its a pretty old application and I think its using version 3.5 of MapPoint Web Service. I would like to know how to set the default zoom level? I would like to get a closer view of the location by default.

I found the MapOptions.Zoom Properties but that looks like how much it zooms each time you hit the button.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just set the MapSpecification.MapOptions.Zoom to a double value. But the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc514567.aspx) will most likely have better answer

Comment: On further testing this actually doesn't work. It is only zoom intensity not default zoom level.